# Counting the number of complete bipartite subgraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

I am stuck with problem and not getting much ideas. I have a graph with $N$ vertices and $M$ edges. I have to count number of ways I can choose a pair of set of vertices say  $(p,q)$, such that every vertex belonging to the set $p$ is connected with every vertices belonging to set $q$ and vice versa.

Given the graph and the cardanality of $p$ and $q$, how to *efficiently* (polynomial time algorithm in terms of vertices and edges) compute the number of assignment?

Example:

Say the graph is of $4 (0,1,2,3)$ vertices and with edges: $$(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2)$$

cardanality of $p$ and $q$ be $1$ and $2$ respectively. Then there are $8$ possible assignments.

$$(\{0\},\{2,3\}), (\{1\},\{2,3\}), (\{2\},\{0,1\}),(\{2\},\{0,3\}),(\{2\},\{1,3\}),(\{3\},\{0,1\}),(\{3\},\{0,2\}),(\{3\},\{1,2\}) $$

Comment: What do you mean with "efficiently"? Do you want a polynomial time algorithm in the the number of nodes and edges?

Comment: @Danny: Yes, I am looking for a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: If you allow yourself a brute force listing for one of the sets, you won't need one for the other. Suppose $|p|$ is the smaller of the cardinalities. For each of the $\binom{N}{|p|}$ subsets, count the number $K$ of columns in the incidence matrix with all 1's when restricted to those rows. Then there are $\binom{K}{|q|}$ sets of cardinality $|q|$ that are assigned to that subset. Sum over all $|p|$-element subsets to obtain the answer. That's a mild speedup over brute force, but a speedup nonetheless.

Comment: I am making the assumption that for a directed graph, any edge $(i,j)$ such that $(j,i)$ is not an edge will be missed by any count due to your "vice-versa" condition. Thus, if given a directed graph, we can delete all such single-directional edges before counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is in #P at least. The decision problem of "Does a bipartite graph has a complete bipartite subgraph $U, W$ with $|U| = |W| = \alpha$?" is NP-complete. Proof in [On Bipartite and Multipartite Clique Problems](http://public.kenan-flagler.unc.edu/faculty/swaminaj/research/paper/DKST.pdf).

Thus, it is unlikely to find a polynomial algorithm to solve this problem.